# Showing the intersection between two strings

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to find the intersection between two strings. For example, if string one was `my car is bad`, and string two was `my horse is good`, it would return `my is`.
This is my code:

```
  public static string intersection2(string x1, string x2)
{
  string[] string1 = x1.Split(' ');
string[] string2 = x2.Split(' ');
string[] m = string1.Distinct();
 string[] n = string2.Distinct();
  string Test;
 var results = m.Intersect(n,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
 Test = results.ToString();
   return Test;

}
```

But I get the error `System.Linq.Enumerable+d__92`1[System.String]`. Could someone explain what's going on, and how I can fix it?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Can you provide some sample inputs and what you're trying to do?

Comment: it should return the intersection between 2 strings ,
String 1 : my car is bad
String 2 : my car vry good 
Result : my car

Comment: `ToString()`'s default behavior on an object is to return the object's type name.  You need to iterate through `results` to show the actual result, or concatenate it with something like `String.Join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing an error - what you are seeing is the fully qualified name of the type of `result`, which is `System.Linq.Enumerable+d_921[System.String]`.  This is the default behavior for `ToString()`, unless it is overridden in an inheriting class.  See [Object.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To show the results of the intersection, you can use `String.Join`, like this:

```
Test = String.Join(" ", results);
```

Which would produce `my is`.

Note that your code as posted wouldn't compile:

```
string[] m = string1.Distinct();
string[] n = string2.Distinct();
```

The above lines generated a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'`.  Adding `.ToArray()` is one way to resolve this.  Full code below:

```
public static string intersection2(string x1, string x2)
{

    string[] string1 = x1.Split(' ');
    string[] string2 = x2.Split(' ');
    string[] m = string1.Distinct().ToArray();
    string[] n = string2.Distinct().ToArray();
    string Test;
    var results = m.Intersect(n, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Test = String.Join(" ", results);
    return Test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is okay, you can make it work by fixing a little bit

```
public static string intersection2(string x1, string x2)
{
    string[] string1 = x1.Split(' ');
    string[] string2 = x2.Split(' ');
    var m = string1.Distinct();
    var n = string2.Distinct();

    var results = m.Intersect(n, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    //The result is a list of string, so we just have to concat them
    var test = " ";
    foreach(var k in results) test += k + " ";
    return test;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/joO0d9

Answer (score 0):

That's basically happened because you tired to get the `string` representation of an `IEnumerable<string>` and it's completely normal because it returns the default `ToString()` of `object` class. So in order to fix that you should somehow make your own string representation, which will be s.t. like this:

```
string[] string1 = x1.Split(' ');
string[] string2 = x2.Split(' ');
string Test;
var results = string1.Intersect(string2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
Test = string.Join(" ", results);
```

also note that there is no need to get `Distinct` result of your arrays, because `Intersect` is a set operation and naturally returns the `Distict` result!

Answer (score 0):

This program gets intersection of 2 strings (assuming duplication is allowed)

```
public String getIntersection(String s1, String s2) {
    String common = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
            if (s1.length() == 0 || s1.length() == 0)
                return common;
            if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)) {
                common = common + s1.charAt(i);
                // delete character from each if there is a match
                s1 = s1.substring(0, i) + s1.substring(i + 1);
                s2 = s2.substring(0, j) + s2.substring(j + 1);
                i = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return common;
}
```